# How to load a Python dict from a textfile into a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, python-import

I have a 2GB file titled 'Apps' that I need to import. The file is composed of nested dictionaries (snippet below). How can I import this in a way that packages the file into a dictionary variable? I realize I could open the file and simply assign, but at 2GB each, I don't want to have to open each file and make the assignment. Thanks

```
{
  'responseHeader':{
    'status':0,
    'QTime':35,
    'params':{
      'sort':'appTitle asc',
      'indent':'true',
      'start':'400',
      'q':'*:*',
      'wt':'python',
      'fq':['status:"A"',
        '-developerWebsite:["" TO *]',
        'intNumDownloads:[0 TO *]'],
      'rows':'450'}},
  'response':{'numFound':771005,'start':400,'docs':[]}}
```

Comment: are you sure it's a python dict? or a json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file contains a well-formed Python dict, you can load it in one line like this:

```
with open('dictfile') as f: my_dict = eval(f.read())
```

The syntax

```
with open(filename) as f:
    # do something
```

is short for

```
f = open(filename)
# do something
f.close()
```

It's a good practice to get into, since it makes sure that your stream is closed at the end. You can use this for database connections, http connections etc as well.

Comment: ? is this the complete syntax: with open('dictfile') as dict

Comment: @BenjaminJames What is the question exactly?

Comment: @maxymoo yes, thank you this is great. Though I'm a little confused as to why the official documentation doesn't explain this in the Modules section

Comment: yeah it took me ages to wrap my head around it, it's kind of weird

Comment: @BenjaminJames never write `... as dict` as it shadows the `dict` class.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, use `import ast; ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @maxymoo I'm having some trouble- I need the variable to be a dictionary object. As it stands, the file is only being recognized as plain text... any suggestions?

Comment: @Benjamin What's the Exception being raised?